# C# web browser select list item click

Tags: c#, select, webbrowser-control

I am trying to select item from select list box using this method:

```
  var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");



        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {

            if (element.GetAttribute("id")=="pagesize")
            {
                element.GetElementsByTagName("option")[2].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
                webBrowser1.Document.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
```

from this html code

```
<select name="pagesize" id="pagesize" onchange="changeFileListRequestSize();">
                <option value="10">10 files per page</option>
                <option value="25" selected="selected">25 files per page</option>
                <option value="50">50 files per page</option>
                <option value="100">100 files per page</option>
                <option value="200">200 files per page</option>
            </select>
```

item is actually changes but that's doesn't execute onchange="changeFileListRequestSize();" javascript event.

how to simulate select list item click or "change"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
document.GetElementById("pageSize").InvokeMember("onchange")
```

Comment: what about  document.GetElementById("pageSize").InvokeMember("onchange") ?

Answer (score -1):

excelent work with this

```
                if (elm.GetAttribute("className").Contains("iceSelOneMnu"))
                {
                    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
                    elm.SetAttribute("value", "630676649");
                    elm.InvokeMember("onchange");
                }
```

Comment: Please add more context on how this will help the OP. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer