# How to simulate click "li" in the WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

There is a site for binary option trading. http://www.beeoptions.com/
On the first page, there is a droplist box contains currencies.
How can I simulate selecting one currency by using WebBrowser Control in c#?
Thanks.

Comment: You can do that with htmlagilitypack! please browse it and find out your question http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes you could use agility pack and WebRequuest to post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really haven't provided enough information for us to give you a definitive answer but here's a best guess.

If you have a look at this SO question ([C# web browser select list item click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875320/c-sharp-web-browser-select-list-item-click)) it says to call

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pageSize").InvokeMember("onchange")
```

If you change that to invoke "click" (as per [How to simulate mouse click with the WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150610/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-with-the-webbrowser-control)) then that should work if you are able to retrieve the appropriate HTML element.

If your li doesn't have an ID then you may need to search for it through different means like [GetElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This SO question may also be of use it covers choosing a select list item ([C# web browser select list item click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875320/c-sharp-web-browser-select-list-item-click))